# Null pointer exception from api response using retrofit in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, retrofit2

I have created a repository class for calling api using retrofit in android studio but I am getting null pointer exception when returning the response. Please have a look at the getUserData() method and comments in it to understand the problem better.

```
public class ContestRepository {

private static ApiInterface apiInterface;
private MutableLiveData<List<User>> userList;
public ContestRepository() {
    apiInterface = RetrofitService.getApiInterface();
    userList = new MutableLiveData<>();
}

public MutableLiveData<List<User>> getUserData() {
    apiInterface.getUserDetails("users").enqueue(new Callback<Root>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Root> call, Response<Root> response) {
            Root result = response.body();
            if(result != null) {
                String status = result.getStatus();
                System.out.println(status);
                if(status.equals("OK")) {
                    userList.setValue(result);
                    System.out.println(userList.getValue().size());  //here userList is not null
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Root> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
    System.out.println(userList.getValue().size());   //here is userList is null
    return userList;
}
}
```

As you can see in code the value of userList is not null when printed in onResponse method and
when printed again before returning it the value becomes null.
I don't understand why this is happening. I know this is some kind of programming mistake but I cannot figure it out. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You are getting your response in background, and you are returning your userLits before you get your data.

Comment: You can use coroutine or flow to solve this kinds of issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(userList.getValue().size());   //here is userList is null
```

This is because you are printing userList before the api gives the response
!!

Comment: can you please tell me what is the appropriate way to return the list in the method?

Comment: get Your data when api gives response as success .

Comment: I used userList.postvalue() instead of .setValue() and it worked.